# Does the Raspberry Pi support I2C multi-master configurations?

Tags: raspbian, python, i2c

We are using Raspberry Pi 2 single board computers for test automation (they run our feature test against an actual DUT).
Our Device Under Test (DUT) uses I2C multi-master mode to communicate with its peripherals.
We would like to use the I2C bus on the Raspberry Pi 2 to interface with the I2C bus on the DUT, however it must support multi-master communication in order for it to be useful.

Can anyone confirm if the I2C bus on the Raspberry Pi supports a multi-master configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the Raspberry Pi does NOT support I2C multi-master mode.

There is no mention of muli-master in the documentation.

> The Broadcom Serial Controller (BSC) controller is a master, fast-mode
> (400Kb/s) BSC controller. The Broadcom Serial Control bus is a
> proprietary bus compliant with the Philips® I2C bus/interface version
> 2.1 January 2000.
>
> • I2C single master only operation (supports clock stretching wait states)
>
> • Both 7-bit and 10-bit addressing is supported.
>
> • Timing completely software controllable via registers

Page 28 [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Am I correct that the newer BCM2836 (RPi2) and BCM2837 (RPi3) have not changed in this aspect?

Comment: The Broadcom "peripherals" are identical on all current Pi models.  So no change for Pi Zero, Pi2B, Pi3B, compute module, etc.