# Arduino slave initiating an I2C transmission to Raspberry Pi master

Tags: i2c, arduino

Is there any way for an Arduino slave to send a byte array to the raspberry pi master without the master having called on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how I2C is specified and supposed to work:

> The aforementioned reference design is a bus with a clock (SCL) and data (SDA) lines with 7-bit addressing. The bus has two roles for nodes: master and slave:
>
> - Master node – node that generates the clock and initiates communication with slaves.
> - Slave node – node that receives the clock and responds when addressed by the master.

<sup>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Reference_design))</sup>

So it is up to the master to initiate any communication whereas the slave may not... and while there is such a thing as a multi-master mode on the I2C bus the Pi does not seem to support that either ([source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/46203/19949)).

So the two relevant options here are:

1) have the Pi as master poll the Arduino on a regular basis to check if it (the Arduino) has any data to transmit.

2) have another GPIO line between the two (output on the Arduino, input on the Pi; mind the voltage levels though). Sort of an [IRQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_(PC_architecture)) - a hardware interrupt request - which allows the Arduino to trigger the Pi to act as a master on the I2C bus and fetch the data as it becomes available.

Comment: 3) use another bus, like UART.